# How to get the user id from laravel passport token?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using smartins/passport-multiauth passport, in PostMan I Made a post request sending this data through the request; 
The idea is when the user submits an order, the token of that user will be passed through the request.. how can I get the user_id of that token so that I can store it in the Orders table?

```
{

        "place_id": 2,
        "token": "b715d124c04125acae2dda144021724b3266a361785f29883105c138d23ecdb0da1fd48de719039a",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "quantity": 5
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "quantity": 3
            }
        ]

}
```

```
public function new_order(Request $request)
    {
        $token= auth('api')->user();
        $order = Order::create([
            'place_id'=>$request->place_id,
            'code_id'=>$request->code_id,
            'user_id'=>$token
        ]);

        $items = $request->input('items', []);
        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            ItemOrder::create([
                'order_id'=>$order->id,
               'item_id'=>$item['id'] ,
               'quantity'=>$item['quantity'] ,
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => (bool)$order,
            'order' => $order,
            'message' => $order ? 'Your order has been sent !' : 'There is some error!'
        ]);
        //ToDo:notificaion to restaurant
    }
```

Comment: `Auth::guard('api')->user()->id` or `auth('api')->user()->id`

Comment: @DilipHirapara I got this error : "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: pass in header

Authorization=Bearer  {your_token}
like this
Authorization =Bearer b715d124c04125acae2dda144021724b3266a361785f29883105c138d23ecdb0da1fd48de719039a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost there... you should pass the id of the user in `$token` like below:

```
$token = auth('api')->user()->id
```

or

```
'user_id' = auth('api')->user()->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
return response()->json([
   'status' => (bool)$order,
   'user_id'=> \Auth::user()->id,
   'order' => $order,
   'message' => $order ? 'Your order has been sent !' : 'There is some error!'
]);
```

Comment: I got this error : "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"

Comment: you pass token in header?

Comment: Yes.I passed the token in header

Comment: this syntax pass Authorization =Bearer b715d124c04125acae2dda144021724b3266a361785f29883105c138d23ecdb0da1fd48de719039a

Comment: like this  "Authorization =Bearer":"9a7659feeb89026d33fefb255c7cdf43a28748b048039becb011b40422a5fa8ccbfb7c1198f66591",   ?

Comment: like this Authorization =Bearer b715d124c04125acae2dda144021724b3266a361785f29883105c138d23ecdb0da1fd48de719039a

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204322/discussion-between-paras-raiyani-and-developer).

Answer (score 0):

just get the authenticated user id like this:

```
'user_id' = auth('api')->user()->id;
```